# Why is the complexity of the BFS O(V + E)?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Consider the algorithm (from another question):

```
set start vertex to visited
load it into queue
    while queue not empty
        for each edge incident to vertex
             if its not visited
                 load into queue
                 mark vertex
```

The complexity of the algorithm is defined as the upper bound of times the inner loop can run, right? Well, considering a complete graph. For each one of its N vertexes, we run the check `if its not visited` `N-1` times. So, that's `N * (N-1)` tests, which is quadratic. What is wrong with this view?

Comment: If you know the answer, you can answer your own question.

Comment: What research have you done?  This is covered by standard textbooks: when they describe DFS and BFS they generally provide an analysis of the running time and explain why the running time is $O(|V|+|E|)$.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research and self-study before asking.  It doesn't benefit anyone to repeat standard material that is covered in standard textbooks on the subject.

Comment: Following on from @YuvalFilmus's comment, not only can you answer your own question but it's [explicitly encouraged](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Note [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) on analysis (simple) algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, BFS accesses (and processes) each edge constant times (twice actually; we assume an undirected graph), costing $O(E)$ total time in edge processing. Similarly, all the vertices are totally accessed (including queue operations and checking operations) $O(E) \cdot O(1)$ times. The overhead for initialization is $O(V)$. Thus the total running time of BFS is $O(V + E)$.

This can be viewed as a simple instance of aggregate analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Each vertex is visited once and each edge twice assuming implementation with an adjacency list so the running time is a constant multiple of the number of edges + number of vertices.  Thus it is O(V + E).

Answer (score -1):

In BFS algorithm  we begin from a arbitary vertex, so we meet all of vertexes then we claim that $O(v)$.since we must meet all vertexes then we used maximum edges to reach other vertexes . so we have $O(V+E)$

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, I can't work out what your argument is, here. What do you mean by "then we used maximum edges to reach other vertices"? What if you got lucky and only looked at $V$ edges? How can you guarantee that edges won't be considered many times each?